Connecting via phpMyAdmin via web browser does not work
I use an AWS EC2 instance, which uses (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) and Bitnami.
I've been logging in through phpMyAdmin (http://localhost:8888/phpmyadmin/) in my web browser for several years to access the database without problems.
A couple of days ago I tried to log in and it said in Mozilla Firefox:
'The connection was reset
The connection to the server was reset while loading the page.'
Error on web browser
When I usually have this problem I usually do the following, I checked my website works fine and also the connection through Putty works correctly to my server.
When I typed the following command in the terminal
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status

I originally got the following message:
apache not running
mysql not running
php-fpm not running

Then I ran
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart

... and now they did run.
apache already running
mysql already running
php-fpm already running

Normally the above allows me to access phpMyAdmin but this time when I tried again it still gives the same error.
I also tried to restart the EC2 instance in AWS. But it didn't work.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Thanks.

Start from the basiscs. Check if you are listening on TCP port 8888. Probably configuration got changed. Localhost is a local machine you would need to use the remote IP/FQDN instead.
